# getting Syntax Error at input '[' when using arrays under Tradingview

Tags: arrays, pine-script

I am using Pinescript under Tradingview.

I am trying to assign a list of items to an array.

```
 //@version=4

study("FTA", overlay=true)
top = input(title="Top", type=input.float, defval=10000, minval=1)
bottom = input(title="Bottom", type=input.integer, defval=5000, minval=0)

plot(bottom , title="bottom" , linewidth=3, color=color.red)
plot(top , title="top" , linewidth=3, color=color.lime)

[ ... snip ...]

res2 = bottom + diff * 2
var ch_2= input(false, "2")
plot( ch_2? res2 : na, title="fib-2", linewidth=3, color=color.lime)

// testing
more_tests = ['Ada', 'Belle', 'Chris']      // LIST OF ITEMS
```

When saving the document, I get this error:

> **Syntax Error at input '['**

**QUESTION: Why am I getting this error**

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not exist in `pine-script`.

What you think an array is called [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) and it is used to access historical values of the previous bars.

You can have a look at [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/2qWuW7xQ-Workaround-for-Arrays-in-pine-and-Bubble-sort/) workaround if you are working with numeric values.

I also have my own workaround which uses a for loop (therefore not as efficient), which I find easier to understand.

```
//@version=4
study("Arrays", max_bars_back=1000)

getValFromArr(src, idx, initVal) =>
    retval = -1.0                       // Return -1.0 in case there is no valid data found
    arrIdx = 0

    for i = 1 to 10000                  // Use a big number for the loop. It is expected that the desired value can be found within this range
        if (not na(src[i]))             // Check if the source has valid value at this index
            if (src[i] == initVal)      // Use the initial value to determine if we have looped through each element of the array
                retval := -1.0
                break                   // Reached the initial value of the array and couldn't found the desired value, so break
            else
                arrIdx := arrIdx + 1    // Array has some valid value at this index, so increase the array index
                if (arrIdx == idx)      // When the array index reaches the desired index
                    retval := src[i]    // Return the value
                    break               // Found the value -> terminate the loop
    retval

// Calculate SMMA
smma = 0.0
smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(close, 7) : (smma[1] * (7 - 1) + close) / 7   // src: close, len: 7

// Write the close value into array when close crosses over smma (condition)
var arrInitVal = -1.0                               // Initial value of the array. Should be set to a value that array won't have further on
var coArr = arrInitVal                              // Declare the array with the initial value
coArr := crossover(close, smma) ? close : na        // Only add value to this series, if it satisfies your conditon! Otherwise, write na!
valAtIdx = getValFromArr(coArr, 2, arrInitVal)      // Get the second last value of coArr
myCo = valAtIdx == -1 ? na : valAtIdx               // Check if the return value is -1, write na or whatever you want in that case

plot(series=coArr, color=color.red, linewidth=2)    // Plot the array. This should only have valid values when the condition is satisfied and na otherwise
plot(series=myCo, color=color.green, linewidth=2)   // This should have the second last value of coArr and keep its value until the contidition is satisfied again
```

The idea behind my workaround is, you only assign a valid value to the "array", if your condition is satisfied. Otherwise, you assign `na`. Then when you want to get a value from the array, you just loop over each historical values of the "array" and look for non `na` values.

In this example, we only want to keep track of values when `close` crosses over `smma` line. So, below line will check for that and add the `close` value to the array, if the condition is met. Otherwise, it will add a `na`.

```
coArr := crossover(close, smma) ? close : na
```

Then you can use the `getValFromArr()` function to get the nth value from last of the array.

Comment: Thanks much! Will check this out